# Rewriting old commits in the master branch

Tags: git, version-control

Say I have this commit history:

```
A - B - C (master)
         \
          D - E - F (Feature)
```

I'd like to amend commit **B**. So, I do:

- git checkout master
- git rebase -i <hash of **A**>

After the rebase is done, I see the change using git log.
However when I switch to the **Feature** branch, commit **B** is still as it was before the rebase.
In other words, when I'm in **master** branch, the commit history looks like this:

```
A - B' - C (master)
```

When I switch to **Feature** branch, the commit history looks like this:

```
A - B - C (master)
         \
          D - E - F (Feature)
```

I understand that rewriting the commit history is not wise, but I have to do this in my case.

How can I amend an old commit and have those changes be reflected on every branch?
Am I doing this the wrong way?

The new commit history will be force pushed into Github and I don't want to mess things up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So far you rebased master successfully as it seems, but now you'd have to rebase Feature on your new version of master.

Comment: Use `git log --all` to see the entire history. (Or `git log --all --graph` for something more understandable.)

Comment: What you need to understand is what exactly is the commit and what is the branch in the git. In short, commits is a snapshot, when the branch is just the reference to certain commit. You can refer to @RomainValeri answer, but please notice that, if you for example didn't have the feature branch, you still do not lose the commit, if you have the hash somewhere (like in command line window or in `reflog`) you still would be able to access that commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your rebase, what you **actually** have is

```
  B'- C' (master)
 /
A - B - C
         \
          D - E - F (Feature)
```

So now to complete the operation you'd have to rebase `Feature` on (the recently rewritten) `master`

```
$ git checkout Feature

$ git rebase master

          D'-E'-F' (Feature)
         /
A - B'- C' (master)
 \       
  B - C - D - E - F (soon to be garbage collected)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me understand the rebase command better.

Answer (score 1):

> and have those changes be reflected on every branch?

You need to manually rebase every branch. There is no way of changing the contents of one branch and have those changes be reflected on other branches, that is antithetical to how Git works.